# Find area of quadrilateral in triangle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area, quadrilateral

What is the area of $HIJK$ quadrilateral, if the area of $ABC$ triangle is $70$, $BE=ED=DA$, and $BF=FG= GC$?

[image]

Comment: I got $\frac{50}{3}.$

Comment: There should be a solution using Ceva's thm or sth.

Comment: The area is $9$. Tthe points $B,I,K$ are collinear and the line containing 
them intersect $AC$ at its midpoint $M$. $\triangle HIK$ is bounded by 3 cevians $AF$, $BM$ and $CD$ with $$(x,y,z) \stackrel{def}{=}\left(\frac{CF}{BF}, \frac{AM}{MC}, \frac{BD}{AD}\right) = (2,1,2)$$
By [Routh's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh's_theorem), area of 
$\triangle HIK$ is
$$\frac{(xyz-1)^2}{(xy+y+1)(yz+z+1)(zx+x+1)}\cdot 70  = \frac{9}{140}\cdot 70 = \frac92$$
By a similar argument, area of $\triangle IJK$ is also $\frac92$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's put the area of 70 on hold for a moment. Furthermore, given the listed constraints and the implicit assumption that the problem is solvable using only those constraints, we choose any proportions for the outer triangle we like.

#### Let's examine the case of a right isosceles triangle with hypotenuse $BC$ and a base length of 3. It has an area of $\frac{9}{2}$.

Letting the origin $(0,0)$ rest at $A$

- $B$ is at $(0,3)$.
- $C$ is at $(3,0)$.
- $D$ is at $(0,1)$.
- $E$ is at $(0,2)$.
- $F$ is at $(1,2)$.
- $G$ is at $(2,1)$.

This gives us the following lines

- $AF$ is $y=2x$
- $AG$ is $y=\frac{1}{2}x$
- $DC$ is $y=-\frac{1}{3}x+1$
- $EC$ is $y=-\frac{2}{3}x+2$

Considering the four batches of two equations with two unknowns yields the coordinates of the remaining four points.

- $H$, from $y=2x,\;y=-\frac{1}{3}x+1$ is $(\frac{3}{7},\frac{6}{7})$.
- $I$, from $y=2x,\;y=-\frac{2}{3}x+2$ is $(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{2})$.
- $J$, from $y=\frac{1}{2}x,\;y=-\frac{2}{3}x+2$ is $(\frac{12}{7},\frac{6}{7})$.
- $K$, from $y=\frac{1}{2}x,\;y=-\frac{1}{3}x+1$ is $(\frac{6}{5},\frac{3}{5})$.

[We can express the general form for the area of a quadrilateral based on it's vertices using vector arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral#Vector_formulas)
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\vert(\vec{J}-\vec{H})\times(\vec{K}-\vec{I})\vert$$
We can plug this into Wolfram Alpha as

```
abs(Cross[([12/7,6/7]-[3/7,6/7]),([6/5,3/5]-[3/4,3/2])])*.5
```

#### Scaling that for our area 70 triangle, gives a final area of 9.

This differs from [Peter Foreman's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3066524/618435), so one of us must have made a typo or a false assumption. **Frankly mine just looks wrong, judging from your diagram.** In any case he deserves credit for advocating such a brute-force approach.

Comment: Thanks! it seems I needed to be more specific to wolfram about what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The area is $\frac{741}{68}$ I'm quite sure. You can find the coordinates of $H,I,J,K$ by using the equations of each straight line and taking $A$ as the origin. I then used Wolfram: Alpha to find the area given the coordinates of each vertex.